# failed resolution of: Lcom/huawei/hms/framework/common/EmuiUtil

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

I'm implementing push notification in Huawei devices and I've got this exception while trying to get token. And this this because of this line:

```
    Client = HmsInstanceId.GetInstance(Application.Context);
```

Exception:

> {Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
> Lcom/huawei/hms/framework/common/EmuiUtil; --->
> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.huawei.hms.framework.common.EmuiUtil" on path: DexPathList[[zip
> file....

The exception message :

> failed resolution of: Lcom/huawei/hms/framework/common/EmuiUtil

How can I solve it?

Comment: hi@Yasmine Abdelsamie, Could you kindly help us with some information to locate this issue? 1. what SDK version are you integrated with? 2. Have you configured obfuscation scripts? And also it would be nice if you could provide your test apk for us to test, you can send it to hmscore@huawei.com.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by downgrading Huawei.Hms.Push package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: hi@Yasmine Abdelsamie, may i confirm which version did you report the error and which version did you downgrading to to solve the problem?

Comment: It was the latest version: 6.1.0.300 and I downgraded it to 5.0.4.302

Answer (score 1):

According to this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-xamarin-bindings/issues/12), installing the NuGet package [Huawei.Hms.NetworkFrameworkCompat](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Huawei.Hms.NetworkFrameworkCompat/) will fix the issue. The install should be done for the Android Project.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the HMS Core SDK is integrated.

For more information, please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/identifier-service-integrating-sdk-0000001056460552-V5?ha_source=hms1.

Comment: I have already checked the integration & It's integrated correctly.